# Dll causes Python to crash when using memset

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, dll, ctypes

I've been working on a project where I'm trying to use an old CodeBase library, written in C++, in Python. What I want is to use CodeBase to reindex a .dbf-file that has a .cdx-index. But currently, Python is crashing during runtime. A more detailed explanation will follow further down.

As for Python, I'm using ctypes to load the dll and then execute a function I added myself which should cause no problems, since it doesn't use a single line of code that CodeBase itself isn't using.
Python Code:

```
import ctypes  
cb_interface = ctypes.CDLL("C4DLL.DLL")  
cb_interface.reindex_file("C:\\temp\\list.dbf")
```

Here's the CodeBase function I added, but it requires some amount of knowledge that I can't provide right now, without blowing this question up quite a bit. If neccessary, I will provide further insight, as much as I can:

```
S4EXPORT int reindex_file(const char* file){
    CODE4 S4PTR *code;
    DATA4 S4PTR *data;

    code4initLow(&code, 0, S4VERSION, sizeof(CODE4));
    data = d4open(code, file);
    d4reindex(data);

    return 1;
}
```

According to my own debugging, my problem happens in code4initLow. Python crashes with a window saying "python.exe has stopped working", when the dll reaches the following line of code:

```
memset( (void *)c4, 0, sizeof( CODE4 ) ) ;
```

c4 here is the same object as code in the previous code-block.

Is there some problem with a dll trying to alter memory during runtime? Could it be a python problem that would go away if I were to create a .exe-file from my python script?

If someone could answer me these questions and/or provide a solution for my python-crashing-problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

And last but not least, this is my first question here. If I have accidently managed to violate a written or unwritten rule here, I apologize and promise to fix that as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Joachim Pileborg saying the problem is, to pass a Nullpointer to code4initLow. ("Alternative") Solution is to allocate Memory for the struct `CODE4 S4PTR *code = (CODE4*)malloc(sizeof(CODE4));`, then pass the Pointer like `code4initLow(code, 0, S4VERSION, sizeof(CODE4));`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the pointer `code` doesn't point anywhere as it is uninitialized. Secondly you don't actually try to fill the structure, since you pass `memset` a pointer *to the pointer*.

What you should probably do is declare `code` as a normal structure instance (and not a pointer), and then use `&code` when passing it to `d4open`.